# Display ProgressBar in middle of Screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

Here is my layout for Activity. And I want to display `android.widget.ProgressBar` in the middle of the screen dynamically.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlSearchToolContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSearchComponentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDone"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Done"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLeftSlide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now In that FrameLayout (id = frameContainer) I replace a Fragment that is BaseFragment.(fragment_base.xml)

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BaseFragment mFileListFragment = new BaseFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, mFileListFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        }
}
```

**fragment_base.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
private View mView;

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mView == null) {
            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_phone_file_base, null);
            setLayoutViews(mView);

        }
        return mView;
    }

       public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FileListFragment mFileListFragment = new FileListFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, mFileListFragment);
        transaction.commit();


        }

}
```

Now In FrameLayout(id = frameContainer) of that BaseFragment I open child fragment that is FileListFragment. (fragment_file_list.xml)

**fragment_file_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rvFileList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FileListFragment.java**

```
public class FileListFragment extends Fragment{
    private View mView;

         @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (mView == null) {
                mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_list, null);
                setLayoutViews(mView);

            }
            return mView;
        }

            @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Here there is a server call which retrieves File Data from server. When I send server request I start progressBar and after response I hide progressBar programatically.

            ProgressBar mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(activity);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
            mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

            FrameLayout listFrame = getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.frameContainer);
            if(listFrame != null) {
                listFrame.addView(mProgressBar);
            }

            }

    }
```

But it doesn't show progressBar in middle of the screen. It displays below of middle of screen like image attached below.

[image]

Comment: You should try to add gravity in framelayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **[android:layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)**

> Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent.

You can align a view in center of the **Framelayout** by setting the **layout_gravity** of the child view .

**`android:layout_gravity="center"`**

Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical and horizontal axis, not changing its size .

Comment: I think that thing won't resolve my problem. The problem is that when you see preview of  **activity_main.xml** in android studio, FrameLayout displays out of screen, because it's height is **match_parent**. I tried to replace height with **wrap_content** but it didn't work. Actually progreeBar displays middle of that frameLayout but some part of framelayout hides behind that bottombar and that's why it shows slightly below of that middle screen.

Comment: @KushPatel Then,i guess you should try with `DisplayMatrix`

Comment: @KushPatel `FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams` this section add `MATCH_PARENT`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you adding progressbar in center of framelayout, try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSearchToolContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearchComponentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDone"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Done"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLeftSlide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using Relativelayout, use Relativelayout as container of progressbar and use centerinparent attribute to center the progressbar in the middle of screen :

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layout.addView(progressBar,params);

setContentView(layout);
```